# Effects of COMPUTE_PROFILE environment variable on running times of OpenCL

Tags: profiling, opencl, fft

I am comparing the running times of an OpenCL FFT code with cudaFFT. My question is related to the COMPUTE_PROFILE environment variable. When it is not set, I get execution times as:

OpenCL: 0.061086 s
CuFFT:  0.032407 s

Showing that cuFFT is faster. Just by setting COMPUTE_PROFILE=1, the execution times are:

OpenCL: 0.023524 s
CuFFT:  0.033270 s

Showing that OpenCL is faster !!! I have compared PTX code in both cases and there is no difference in both cases. What exactly is happening here? Any ideas.

Comment: How are you taking the timings in both the `COMPUTE_PROFILE=0` and `COMPUTE_PROFILE=1` cases? By setting `COMPUTE_PROFILE=0`, you are disabling the command line profiler.

Comment: Interesting, what is the default value?

Comment: I am getting the timings by getting the difference of  'CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START' and 'CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START'. I then convert it into seconds.
DarkZeros, this environment variable is not enabled by default.

Comment: Please read "difference of CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START and CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END" in above comment.